# Bootstrap Responsive Grid System

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I am making a section that contain some text but i need the text in the right half of the section and on the left there is a background image for the section, so i made col-md-4 for the unused half because i don't wanna hide the background image and col-md-8 to the text, how to hide the col-md-4 section on the small screen and let the col-md-8 cover the whole section? iam using bootstrap 5

the code:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x/Twitter Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="header-main row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8 text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items center">
    <h1 class="first-font">MOBI TECH</h1>
    <h2 class="second-font my-4">THE CHEAPEST PRICE<br>THE BEST QUALITY</h2>
    <a class="btn-light-outline first-font px-5 py-2 rounded-pill">SHOP NOW</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

the output on desktop:

[image: Desktop View]

the output on phones:

[image: Phone View]

Answer (score 2):

To hide element on particluar screen breakpoint use `.d-sm-none .d-md-block`

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x/Twitter Library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="header-main row">
  <div class="col-md-4 .d-sm-none .d-md-block"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 text-center d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items center">
    <h1 class="first-font">MOBI TECH</h1>
    <h2 class="second-font my-4">THE CHEAPEST PRICE<br>THE BEST QUALITY</h2>
    <a class="btn-light-outline first-font px-5 py-2 rounded-pill">SHOP NOW</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

this will leave layout as you defined for `md` screens and hide firs div and make second div `12 cols` wide on `sm` screens.

Comment: thank you for your time but it's not hid yet

Comment: Since you have included info you are using Bootstrap 4 now, you must use `.d-sm-none .d-md-block` as hidden classes are gone in there. I have edited the answer